# Azure Search facets and filter

Tags: e-commerce, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search on my e-commerce site, and now want to implement filtering and I can't choose right way to do is. The problem is that I have really different product types, so they have various attributes (properties) and I don't want to create index with 50 attribute fields to faced them all. Another way - I can define few properties (like Attribute1, Attribute2 ... ) and then determine their 'Key' names according to facated values, but it sound not so good too. Is there some common or checked way to build filters on e-commerce sites?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Search will do well if you have 50 fields that have sparse values. Assuming that sparseness comes with relatively low per-facet cardinality, it shouldn’t have a bad performance impact, and by explicitly modeling stuff as fields you get to keep the nice and clean programming model that comes from having explicit fields.

The attribute mapping thing would work assuming all facets are of the same data type or can be grouped easily.

Another thing you can do for string facets is to have a prefix in the facet value (e.g. Cameras/Canon, Memory/MiniSD, etc.). That gives you counts per value within the parent scope. If you also have the parent scope (e.g. Camera, Memory) in a separate field you can filter by the whole scope if needed. This generalizes well into hierarchical facets (as long as they are all strings). [Here is a blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/onsearch/2015/09/09/multi-level-taxonomy-facets-in-azure-search/) that explores this technique.